# Best way to convert DOCX to EPUB?

Tags: epub, calibre, conversion, libreoffice, pandoc

Which is best for converting DOCX to EPUB? Pandoc, LibreOffice, or Calibre?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, Pandoc doesn't preserve all the color and formatting. Calibre and LibreOffice do. Calibre, however, doesn't preserve comments and inline things, but LibreOffice does. So, LibreOffice (probably ∵ of it's extensive Doc format parsing abilities) is the best to convert to EPUB, and it outputs EPUB 3`s by default.

Answer (score 0):

Calibre has worked well for me, but depending on how much special formatting, images, etc. you have, you'll need to do a lot of touch-up work. You may end up wishing you just started from scratch.

But having done a project like that once, I think it was still easier to convert using Calibre then make adjustments and changes.

I have not used PanDoc. LibreOffice is worth trying, too. Try both LibreOffice and Calibre and see which is better. They're both free, and both simple to use.